# pageup or page down keystrokes not recorded when recording automation test scripts

Tags: ruby, automation, pagedown

In trying to test a website for inserting text but the element needing the text inserted is out of view, which has causes the script to fail. I need to scroll the scroll bar, press the page down key or pres the space bar to move the webpage.  I am using ruby to code the automated test and have not found any code to mimic any of these keystrokes. What can I do to mimic the pressing the page down key?

Comment: How are you automating the website? "using ruby" is a bit vague. Usually there is a gem that is used to automate websites - for example "selenium-webdriver", "watir", etc.

Comment: Can you tell us some more about the tools you are using? Are you using some specific test framework?

Also: is it not possible to find the element in the DOM, like referring to it by ID? It isn't clear to me why it is necessary to simulate scrolling.